# How to insert ManyToMany field in django

Tags: python, django

I want to insert a ManyToMany fields in my db using django.I select some customers using checkboxes.
This is my models.py :

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    channel = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_date = models.DateField()
    end_date = models.DateField()
    target_prospect = models.ManyToManyField(ProspectClient,related_name='campaigns_prospect')
    target_partner = models.ManyToManyField(PartnerClient,related_name='campaigns_partners')
```

I try the code below in my views.py but didn't work :

```
def campaigns_page(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.user.profile == 'D' or request.user.profile == 'E' or request.user.is_superuser:
            campaigns = Campaign.objects.all()
            prospects = ProspectClient.objects.all()
            partners = PartnerClient.objects.exclude(id__in=PartnerClient.objects.values('id')).all()
            context = {
                'campaigns':campaigns,
                'prospects':prospects,
                'partners':partners
            }
            if request.method == 'POST':
                title = request.POST['title']
                channel = request.POST['channel']
                start_date = request.POST['start_date']
                end_date = request.POST['end_date']
                descriptions = request.POST['goals'].split(",")
                targets = request.POST['targets']
                campaign = Campaign.objects.create(title=title,channel=channel,start_date=start_date,end_date=end_date)
                for description in descriptions:
                    goal = Goal.objects.create(description=description)
                    goal.campaign.add(campaign)
                for target in targets:
                    prospects.campaign.add(campaign)
                    partners.campaign.add(campaign)
            return render(request,'CampaignManagement/campaigns_page.html',context)
    return render(request, 'Login/logout.html')
```

If I delete the part of tergets it works.
But with this part it gives me This error : `'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'campaign'`
How I can solve this ?

Comment: Describe what didn’t work? Did you receive errors? Did any of it work?

Comment: @Jarvis I edit my question

Comment: Add your `Goal` model. Error is in this line `goal.campaign.add(campaign)`

Comment: The error is in these lines : `for target in targets:
                    prospects.campaign.add(campaign)
                    partners.campaign.add(campaign)`

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of errors.  Perhaps one or more are leading to the problem.

**One**
Try printing this:

```py
partners = PartnerClient.objects.exclude(id__in=PartnerClient.objects.values('id')).all()
print(partners)
```

I suspect it will print `None` since you are excluding all `id`'s in `PartnerClient.objects.values('id')`.  On another note you don't need the `all()` since `exclude()` will return all the results you are looking for.

**Two**
In the line `for target in targets:` what exactly are you iterating through?  `targets = request.POST['targets']` is just giving you a string, so it would iterate through each letter.  Perhaps you meant:

```py
targets = request.POST['targets'].split(", ")
```

like you did for `descriptions`?  Or perhaps you are getting a list of items from your form, in which case you can use:

```py
targets = request.POST.getlist('targets')
```